# Why passing struct to function with literal struct parameter from current package differs from the same for function from another package?

Tags: struct, go

This works perferctly:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Struct struct {
    field string
}
func Fn(arg struct{field string}) {
    fmt.Println(arg)
}

func main() {
    Fn(Struct{"john"})
}
```

But this gives `./main.go:12: cannot use Struct literal (type Struct) as type struct { field string } in argument to sub.Fn`:

*main.go*

```
package main

import "go_tests/sub"

type Struct struct {
    field string
}

func main() {
    sub.Fn(Struct{"john"})
}
```

*sub/sub.go*

```
package sub

import "fmt"

func Fn(arg struct{field string}) {
    fmt.Println(arg)
}
```

Only change in function call is that `Fn(Struct{"john"})` was replaced with `sub.Fn(Struct{"john"})`.

Why moving function to another package affects types logic? Links to the docs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export your struct field:

```
type Struct struct {
    Field string
}
```

and then also change the call to use the exported field:

```
func Fn(arg struct{Field string}) {
    fmt.Println(arg)
}
```

From the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) (specifically the last sentence):

> For struct literals the following rules apply:
>
> - A key must be a field name declared in the LiteralType.
> - An element list that does not contain any keys must list an element for each struct field in the order in which the fields are declared.
> - If any element has a key, every element must have a key.
> - An element list that contains keys does not need to have an element for each struct field. Omitted fields get the zero value for that
>     field.
> - A literal may omit the element list; such a literal evaluates to the zero value for its type.
> - It is an error to specify an element for a non-exported field of a struct belonging to a different package.