# Unable to pass struct type argument to a function in another package

Tags: go, struct

I have two packages: offer.go and parser.go. I have a variable `cart` of type struct `Data`. I want to pass it as an argument to a function which is in another package `parser`. However I am not able to do that. Please look into the following:

offer.go

```
package offer

import "go_tests/Parser"

type Data struct {
    Id       int
    Quantity int
    Mrp      float64
    Discount float64
}
cart := make(map[int]Data)
//cart has some data in it
//passing it to parser
Parser.BXATP(offer_id, rule.Description, cart, warehouseId)
```

parser.go

```
package Parser

type Data struct {
    Id       int
    Quantity int
    Mrp      float64
    Discount float64
}

func BXATP(offer_id int, rule string, cart map[int]Data, warehouseId int){
 //my code is here
}
```

However running this, gives me following error:

```
 cannot use cart (type map[int]Data) as type map[int]Parser.Data in argument to Parser.BXATP
```

I found this link but the solution doesn't seem to work in my case:

[Why passing struct to function with literal struct parameter from current package differs from the same for function from another package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657109/why-passing-struct-to-function-with-literal-struct-parameter-from-current-packag)

I change the parser to :

```
func BXATP(offer_id int, rule string, cart map[int]struct {
    Id       int
    Quantity int
    Mrp      float64
    Discount float64
}, warehouseId int)
```

But now error is :

```
 cannot use cart (type map[int]Data) as type map[int]struct { Id int; Quantity int; Mrp float64; Discount float64 } in argument to Parser.BXATP
```

I don't understand how to achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have `Data` defined in two packages? If you need the exact same structure, just have it in one package. If you leave it in `parser`, you can do something like:

```
package offer

import "go_tests/Parser"

cart := make(map[int]Parser.Data)
//cart has some data in it
//passing it to parser
Parser.BXATP(offer_id, rule.Description, cart, warehouseId)
```

Types defined in separate packages are different even if they share name and underlying structure. So `Parser.Data` is not compatible with `offer.Data`.

Comment: I am using type `Data`  in the package offer in so many other places also where the code is not related to parser. Is there a way I can use `Data` from  offer package in Parser Package?

Comment: Not without causing circular import error. You can't import `offer` into `Parser` as `offer` is already importing `Parser`. One solution is to move the type out into a third package and import that into both `offer` and `Parser`.

Comment: Also, you can still use `Data` in `offer`. Just use `Parser.Data` everywhere in `offer` and remove `Data` from `offer`. They are still the same structures so unless you have methods defined on the type, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: yes I know that.  I actually tried importing offer to parser. I thought if there might be any other solution. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign every single struct field to another struct field, see example:

```
package parser

import "./offer"

type Data struct {
    Id       int
    Quantity int
    Mrp      float64
    Discount float64
}
 func main(){

     offer_data := &offer.Data{} 

     parser_data :=  &Data{
         Id: offer_data.Id,
         Quantity: offer_data.Quantity,
         Mrp: offer_data.Mrp,
         Discount: offer_data.Discount,
     }
 }
```